# Como carregar um vídeo do Vimeo já com o intervalo de tempo recuperado da função getPlayed()?

Tags: javascript, api, vídeo, vimeo-api

Estou usando a api do Vimeo para exibir vídeos e estou tentado rastrear o total que o usuario assistiu do vídeo.

Estou usando a função getPlayed() que me retorna um array() de 2 posição:

```
played[0][0] = onde o vídeo começou
played[0][1] = onde o vídeo parou
```

assim se o usuário pular parte do vídeo ele vai gerando os break points e consigo calcular exatamente a porcentagem assistida, no final fica um array tipo assim:

```
played[
    [
      0,
      3.121989
    ],
    [
      6.592178,
      7.665579
    ],
    [
      11.340782,
      12.800453
    ],
    [
      21.508379,
      22.679186
    ],
    [
      28.324022,
      29.420229
    ]
  ]
```

Até ai tudo bem, consigo recuperar os valores e calcular a porcentagem.

O problema que não estou achando como iniciar o vídeo já com esses intervalos preenchidos para que eu consiga rastrear as partes que o usuário já assistiu e continuar de onde ele parou.

Referencias:

https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/reference#methods-for-playback-controls
https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/#embed-options

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.